# Using AWS Elemental MediaStore as a backend for MediaPackage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elemental, aws-mediastore, aws-mediapackage

I think what I want to do is utilize MediaStore as a backend to MediaPackage, but it's possible mediaPackage has everything I need I just haven't been able to find any answers.

What I'm looking for is a way to record live video, and have it available for playback.  I was looking at [this solution from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/live-streaming-with-automated-multi-language-subtitling/architecture.html) for livestreaming, and while it is close to what I want I want to store the video for playback at a later date as well as broadcast the video live.

My customer also wants the ability to upload videos that were not live recorded, so I think what I want to do is add MediaStore between the lambda function and MediaPackage, so I can upload videos to MediaStore manually or setup a channel within MediaStore for live streams.  Then I can have MeidaPackage reference the MediaStore to create the different file formats for consumption.  The problem is that MediaPackage doesn't accept a MediaStore endpiont, only an S3 endpoint.

Any advice?
TTIA

Answer (score 1):

Using S3 and MediaPackage should be sufficient in your case. It is not necessary to use MediaStore.

I am assuming you are using AWS MediaLive or encoder from other vendor to create a HLS feed that ingest to MediaPackage. In MediaPackage, you can create endpoints as needed. This AWS Media Service Simple Live workflow should give you the idea how to build the workflow. [1]

To record the live video or create live to VOD asset, you can create a harvest job in MediaPackage. MediaPackage will harvest the timeframe that you indicated in the harvest job and will save the copy in your S3 Bucket. For more information please read this article. [2]

To playback the live to VOD asset or a upload video, you can use the VOD functionality in MediaPackage to make the asset available for playback. For more information please read this article. [3]

[1] https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-simple-live-workflow

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/ltov-how.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/vod-content.html